# Is it permissible to ask allah to have a Muslim jinn friend And can you ask it to do favours that humans can do such as homework

Tags: jinn

Can we ask allah to have a Muslim jinn friend and can we ask it to do favours or is it shirk

Answer (score 3):

Islam **forbids** us from taking or using the service of Jinn as it is *haram* in the Islamic law.

Asking for help from the jinn will make them even more arrogant and worse. Allah Almighty says:

> *"And there were men from mankind who sought refuge in men from the*
> *jinn, so they [only] increased them in burden."* **Al-Jinn [72:6]**

Therefore, using jinn services is prohibited to block the path that could lead to damage our faith. This is known as the sadd al-zari'ah.

Wallahualam.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to say "genocide." Genocide means the systematic killing of an ethnic group. You probably had another word in mind.

Comment: @TheZ Thank you for pointing out. I've corrected it with much simpler words.

Answer (score 1):

NO

You cannot interact with the world of jinn.

However some people do this. They are magicians .

When the world of Jinn and the World of Men overlap, then it's called Sihr  (magic).

Asking a Jinn for its services is essentially Sihr  ( magic) and equal to Shirk as well, because the Jinn will ask you to worship him.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Sihr is a Major Sin

Answer (score 0):

Doing homework is your responsibility and if someone is doing it for you then its haram because its a sort of cheating. It is strictly prohibited to seek help for your needs other than ALLAH.

Comment: This answer is off topic. He basically asks if he could be friend with a jinn, the homework was just an example of something less important I assume. Also you didn't not add any evidences or references that doing other people's homeworks are haram..

Comment: Home work example shows his intention of what he wants to do with this power, so it is very relevant. Secondly cheating is haram in Islam because its a sort of deception. Sahi Muslim Hadith 191-192 "A person who deceives is not one of us".

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of whether we are really allowed to ask help from Jinn for "good things". In Surah Az-Zariyat (QS 51:56) it says that Allah created jinn and humans to worship only Him. So, let's just say you ask a jinn for "help" in praying to Allah for/with you (e.g. for health) but at the same time you CONTINUE to pray to Allah SWT, will this be wrong?

My logic, if you can call it that, is that will it not be similar to when you ask a fellow Muslim to pray for you? We are, after all, creatures of Allah Azza Wa Jallah. Points to wonder.